# getting error while importing .class files in a project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, .class-file

I made a java project. It has dependencies. I have the class files. So what i did i made a classes folder and put all the class files in that folder and then add that folder to my project. All the dependencies have been removed. But i think class files also have anonymous classes. SO i am getting error at that line. Here is my project structure

[image: Error]

The error that i am getting is

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.suprema.ufe33.UFScannerClass$UFS_SCANNER_PROC. Fix the build path then try building this project
>
> The type com.suprema.ufe33.UFScannerClass$UFS_SCANNER_PROC cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

How can i solve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477947/how-to-import-class-file-in-a-java-file

Comment: What is `com.suprema.ufe33.UFScannerClass`? Is this a class you wrote yourself? Or is this a class from a 3rd party library?

Comment: @Code-Guru I just got the .class files from some one. I didn't write myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the folder structure you created in the `classes/` folder does not exactly match the package name of the classes you are referencing. Check the capitalization of  `ufe33`.

By the way, it's usually better/easier to use a JAR of such dependencies instead of folders of `.class` files.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. Yes `E-Riz` is right that folder structure is not right. It should be small `ufe33`. Also i created the jar. What i did is I ran this command where i copy all the four class files.

> D:\jars>jar cf myjar.jar com\suprema\ufe33*.class

It made the jar file `myjar.jar`. Then i simply add this jar to my eclipse project class path and the problem solved.